# Repeat bar errors

Tags: lilypond

I'm triyng to have the second line open at the end as the first. But with repeats bar at the third line the second line get a bar and if I try to overrite with \once \hide Staff.BarLine also the bar at the third line disappears. What's the correct way to do it?
Thank you.

[image]

[Here](http://lilybin.com/ipklhh/1) is my minimal code.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you are asking for, but if you want an invisible bar line try `\bar""`

Comment: I want the second line without bar. \bar"" doesn't work.

Comment: @Mahanidhi Could you make sure your minimal code is able to be compiled? Also, I wonder if the repeat at the start of the third line is part of the issue; LilyPond might force a barline at the end of the second system since a repeat is about to start.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the \include-all file: http://lilybin.com/6s1z36/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with the `break-visibility` property.

Add `\once \override Score.BarLine.break-visibility = #'#(#f #t #t)`.

More about the `break-visibility` property [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/visibility-of-objects#using-break_002dvisibility).

Minimal example:

```
\score {
    \new Staff {
        \relative c' {
        \key des \major
        \cadenzaOn
        \repeat volta 2 {
            des4 ees f2
            des4 ees f2 \bar "" \break
            des4 ees f2
            des4 ees f2
        }
        des4 ees f2 \once \override Score.BarLine.break-visibility = #'#(#f #t #t) \break
        \repeat volta 2 {
            des4 ees f2
            des4 ees f2
        }
        }
    }
}
```